# Direct3D Output on a Printer/Plotter

Tags: graphics, printing, directx, plot, direct3d

What is the best way to send Direct3D output to a printer or a plotter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it by creating a BMP file from the front buffer and then printing that BMP:

http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/screengrab.htm

Answer (score 1):

I would like to say that sending screenshot or image is only suitable for printers (raster graphic). If you want to draw on the plotter, you'll need use the special instruction for the particular model of plotter you intended to draw on. Plotters are restricted to draw only line art as oppose to raster graphics. Take a look at this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plotter)

Answer (score 0):

I would just take a screenshot of the entire 3d scene, and then print it out.

Comment: Thanks. I found a more detailed explanation here:
http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/tilerender/index.htm